# Incompatible Types With User Created Structures

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures, error-handling, typedef

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [“Assignment from incompatible pointer type” warning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755637/assignment-from-incompatible-pointer-type-warning)

I have two structures, one which builds off the other. My hope is to use them together to create an adjacency list for a directed weighted graph.

Here are my structures:

```
typedef struct{
        int v;
        int edgeWeight;
        struct adjEdge * next;
}adjEdge;

typedef struct{
        int v;
        int weight;
        struct  adjEdge *adj;
}vertex;
```

So basically the vertex adj will be null unless there is a connection to another vertex, which is the adjEdge structures function.

My issue is that when I assign a adjEdge to the vertex structure I am getting an error:

```
bfs.c:75: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type
```

Here is part of the code. Look to it to see where the errors are actually being thrown

```
while((fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d", &u, &v, &w)) != EOF)
{
    vertexArray[u-1].v = u;


    adjEdge * newEdge;
    newEdge->v = v;
    newEdge->edgeWeight = w;
    newEdge->next = NULL;

    if(vertexArray[u-1].adj = NULL)
    {
        vertexArray[u-1].adj = newEdge; //error
    }
    else
    {
        adjEdge * traverse = vertexArray[u-1].adj; //error
        while(traverse->next != NULL)
        {
            traverse = traverse->next; //error
        }
        traverse->next = newEdge;  //error
    }
}
```

I thought once declared in my structures I could utilize assignments like this?

Comment: Try something like `typedef struct adjEdge{.....}Edge;` and then in other struct you should use something like `Edge *adj;`

Comment: i'm thinking thats what i did...?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8755836/1410711) can be helpful I guess...

Comment: @ZAX: You are doing `typedef struct { ... } adjEdge`. The suggestion is to do `typedef struct adjEdge { ... } adjEdge`.

Comment: @sharth thanks for clearing that up! It did the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the way you have defined structures. Define them as follows and get rid of the warnings.

```
typedef struct adjEdge_{
        int v;
        int edgeWeight;
        struct adjEdge_ * next;
}adjEdge;

typedef struct vertex_{
        int v;
        int weight;
        struct  adjEdge_ *adj;
}vertex;
```

Hope this helps!