# Why does typedef'ing cause an error with structs that have fields that reference itself?

Tags: c, struct, typedef

I had a weird bug trying while trying to understand structs better and I'd like to understand it better. I was trying to create a small linked list without using malloc() and printing one of them by referring to it via the .next field of the previous node and using -> notation.

I had the following code:

```
1 #include<stdio.h>
2 #include<stdlib.h>
3
4 int main(){
5
6     typedef struct {
7         int data;
8         struct node *next;
9     }node;
10
11     node m;
12     m.data = 350;
13     m.next = NULL;
14
15     node n;
16     n.data = 2;
17     n.next = &m;
18   
19     printf("%d %d \n", m.data, n.next->data);
20     return 0;
21
22 }
```

and I was getting an error on line 17 saying:

"warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  n.next = &m;"

and an error on line 19 saying:

" error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  printf("%d %d \n", m.data, n.next->data);"

However, someone changed the code slightly and made the code work. Here is the functional code:

```
1 #include<stdio.h>
2 #include<stdlib.h>
3
4 int main(){
5
6     typedef struct nodey{
7         int data;
8         struct nodey *next;
9     }node;
10
11     node m;
12     m.data = 350;
13     m.next = NULL;
14
15     node n;
16     n.data = 2;
17     n.next = &m;
18    
19     printf("%d %d \n", m.data, n.next->data);
20     return 0;
21
22 }
```

It seems the error has something to do with the compiler not being able to see that &m goes by the typedef name. Would you be able to explain why this is an error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755637/assignment-from-incompatible-pointer-type-warning

Answer (score 3):

Typedefs and structs have different namespaces.  When referencing a struct, it must be prefixed by the `struct` keyword.

```
 typedef struct {
     int data;
     struct node *next;
 }node;
```

This defines an anonymous struct with an alias of `node`.  So the typdef `node` is defined but `struct node` has not been defined.  Note however that this effectively declares `struct node` without defining it.

When you later do `n.next = &m`, you're attempting to assign a `node *` to a `struct node *`, and these are not the same.

```
 typedef struct nodey{
     int data;
     struct nodey *next;
 }node;
```

This defines a struct named `struct nodey`, and declares `node` as an alias for `struct nodey`.

Comment: Old code should have failed to compile at line 8 because 'struct node' is not known at that point. Why did it not fail?

Comment: @NulledPointer in C , using `struct foo` anywhere that a typename is expected causes that to be declared as a type

Comment: Nothing prevents you from using the same struct tag and type definition, so just do `typedef struct node { struct node* next; } node;`. It all refers to the very same struct so it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

```
typedef struct {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}node;
```

First, `struct node` isn't (yet) a thing, so you're declaring a new `struct node` type here that's distinct from `node`. Did you mean to use just `node`?

Second, you can't make use of the `typedef` within your `struct` declaration 
because you're still in the middle of defining your new type alias. That is, within your `struct` declaration, the compiler has not finished processing the `typedef` yet.  Therefore if you want to use the `typedef` within the `struct` definition, you will need to disentangle the declarations:

```
typedef struct nodey node;

struct nodey {
    int data;
    node *next;
};
```

(For what it's worth, in C++ where `struct` and `class` declarations automatically create type aliases, such disentanglement is not necessary.)

Comment: @M.M Oops. Updated.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from using the same struct tag and type definition, so just do `typedef struct node { struct node* next; } node;`. It all refers to the very same struct so it makes sense.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, I know.  That's what the OP did in the second case.  I was demonstrating how to use the `typedef` within the `struct` definition.